# Rebind function when change DOM after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the height of an element before and after an ajax call to change the content of this element (for learning reasons).

Example:

```js
$(document).ready()
     calcHeigth('#listar-cursos');       
 });
funcion calcHeigth(idElement){
   console.log($(idElement).outerHeight(true));
}
```

```html
<div id="listar-cursos">all the content is here</div>
```

When the document is ready, `calcHeigth` function returns 200px.

There is a form on that page that is sent by ajax and when the request ends I just empty the contents of the element, and then call `calcHeigth` again (in `ajaxComplete` event).

```js
$("#formSeacrh").submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            var data = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#listar-cursos").html("");                  
                },
                complete: function () {
                    Completo();                    
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    Carregando();
                },
                error: function () {
                    Falha();                    
                },
                ajaxComplete: function () {
                    calcHeigth('#listar-cursos');
                }
            })            

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

The result from `calcHeigth` is always 200px, like when the document is ready, even with the empty element. `calcHeigth` not realized that the element was changed. The result that I expected was 40px. How to fix and get the current height?

Comment: Do you have any CSS you can share?  e.g. `#listar-cursos { height: 200px }` ?

Comment: just a padding. The content of this element is so dynamic your size ranges
#listar-cursos{padding:20px 0}

Comment: Your first code snippet throws a syntax error. Your second... frankly I'm surprised it even calls your function, considering `ajaxComplete` is not a valid property in the ajax settings.

Comment: `$(idElement).outerHeight(true)` has to be `$(idElement)[0].outerHeight(true)` because `$(idElement)` is a JQuery Object and `outerHeight` is a Vanilla function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry I'm new here and haven't learned how to ask the right way. All these functions I found googling and reading a little bit about jquery already realized that are incorrect. But the main thing I'd like to know is how to understand changes in the function element after the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formSeacrh").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#listar-cursos").html("");   
                Completo();
                calcHeigth('#listar-cursos');
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                Carregando();
            },
            error: function () {
                Falha();                    
            }
        })            
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

you only need 1 ready function, not 3. i hope this works now how you wish.

if you do your calc after your clear the html from the node, the height should be 0.

by the way. `$('listar-cursos').empty()` is better than `.html("")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is a css element which causes the result return 40px.
#listar-cursos{padding:20px;} Sorry I'm new here and haven't learned how to ask the right way. I tried your solution but the function continues to return the height of the element before the ajax request change it.
The function does not realize that the element has changed.